# UTF-8 GET request parameters in php

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, get, echo

I've got the following URL :

http://my-server/method.php?search_string=%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA ( url-encoded word - "Парик" ).

And i've for the following script :

```
<?php
    include 'BL_DBHelper.php';

    header( "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />") ;

    $searchString = $_GET['search_string'];

    echo $searchString ; 
?>
```

Supprisingly, server output is : "
ÐÐ°ÑÐ¸Ðº". What encoding problems do i have? I also cannot send this variable to DB-queues procedures, it's in wrong encoding also(

Comment: Your URL is correctly encoded. Try `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Well, no - @chris85 answer is correct - i had to change headers)